# angualrjs: escape slashes from parameter value passed to $http.get

Tags: angularjs

I am using a simple HTTP GET call in angularjs and passing some query string parameters.

One of the param is a date. Let's say "update" and the value passed is 03/20/2015.

When I make $http.get call passing the "update" as query string parameter,

the request is sent as

http://myservice.com/services/products?update=03%2F20%2F2015

I would like to send it as

http://myservice.com/services/products?update=03/20/2015

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This will be decoded on the back-end. To better understand your question, why do you want to do this?

Comment: I asked backend people to decode it and they refused to do so.  Just want to make sure if there is a way to do it on the front end

Comment: You can format your date with $filter.  Something like this : `date = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'M/dd/YYYY', "UTC/GMT")`. Useful link: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to replace slashes with dashes in the date: 03-20-2015
[here](http://www.leakon.com/archives/865) you can find some more informations

Answer (score 0):

`%2F` is just the encoded url for '/', your back-end could decode it automatically.

Comment: I agree. I use a lot of params with spaces (`%20`) and never manually encode/decode.

Comment: The URL-encoded characters for a slash are `%2F` not `%2`

Comment: @CarlosP Thank you for your comment, I have just modified my answer.